# LatLong Values in Toast

Tags: android, json, arraylist

I used Json to retrieve LatLong values then i saved these values in in LatLang object now i want to show that in toast so ensure that values are saved

```
for (int i = 0; i < matchFixture.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = matchFixture.getJSONObject(i);
                    Double matchId = Double.valueOf(c.getString(TAG_Latitude));
                    Log.d("matchId", String.valueOf(matchId));
                    Double teamA = Double.valueOf(c.getString(TAG_Longitude));
                    Log.d("teamA", String.valueOf(teamA));

                    //  hashmap for single match
                    matchFixtures = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    matchFixtures.put(TAG_Latitude, String.valueOf(matchId));
                    matchFixtures.put(TAG_Longitude, String.valueOf(teamA));

                    matchFixtureList.add(matchFixtures);
                     latLng=new LatLng(matchId,teamA);
                    System.out.print("herejj"+latLng);


                }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Long: " + String.valueOf(matchId) + ", Lat: " + String.valueOf(teamA), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```